# Real valued and holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

I was wondering about this problem for a while out of curiosity:  is there a non-constant analytic function with real values on  $\mathbb{R}$ and purely imaginary values $i\mathbb{R}$?

I think the answer is a no by using Cauchy-Riemann equations but somehow I can't formulate it right. Your help is appreciated.

---

So sorry I made a mistake in writing the question.

Comment: If $f(z)=z$ on $\mathbb R$, then $f(z) = z$ also on $i \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want $f(z)$ to be analytic on $\mathbb C$ such that $f(z) \in \mathbb R$ when $z \in \mathbb R$ and $f(z) \in i \mathbb R$ when $z \in i \mathbb R$, $f(z)$ can be any given by any series with infinite radius of convergence that has the form $\sum_{j=0}^\infty c_j z^{2j+1}$ where $c_j$ are real.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(z)=z^2$. (More characters I guess...)

Comment: Beat me by a second! :)

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in writing my question.

Comment: @Spock $f(z)=z$?